# How to 'merge' multiple objects as one json object while reading data from csv file

Tags: json, node.js, csv

I want to convert some csv file into json file in nodejs.

While, some of property in the json will be array. Right now I can read a csv file row by row like this:

```
{"price":1,"bedrooms":"Bedrooms (All Levels): 4"},
{"price":null,"bedrooms":"Bedrooms (Above Grade): 4"},
{"price":null,"bedrooms":"Master Bedroom: 21x15"},
{"price":null,"bedrooms":"Master Bedroom Bath: Full"},
{"price":null,"bedrooms":"2nd Bedroom: 14x13"},
{"price":null,"bedrooms":"3rd Bedroom: 15x14"},
{"price":null,"bedrooms":"4th Bedroom: 15x12"}
```

BUT I want to get something like this:

```
`{"price":1,"bedrooms":["Bedrooms (All Levels): 4","Bedrooms (Above 
Grade): 4","Master Bedroom: 21x15","Master Bedroom Bath: Full","2nd 
Bedroom: 14x13","3rd Bedroom: 15x14","4th Bedroom: 15x12"]}`
```

Can someone point out some ways? I tried things like fast-csv,csv-parse,ect. But couldn't merge(push or append) the values of the same field into one field as an array.
Thanks.

the code I finished right now:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('fast-csv');
var stream = fs.createReadStream("../../HouseDataDev01.csv");
csv
.fromStream(stream, {columns:true, ignoreEmpty:true, headers : 
["price","bedrooms"]})
.on("data", function(data){
//      console.log(data);
})
.on("end", function(){
    console.log("done");
});
```

==========

I came up with an idea that maybe I can create an object

```
var NewHouse = require('../models/NewHouse.js'); 
//NewHouse is a schema I created before to store the csv data

var test = new NewHouse;
```

So that I can use the test object something like this:

```
.on("data", function(data){
        for(i in test){
            test.i.push(data[index];
        }
```

But I found there are many other properties in test like:$__reset, $__dirty, $__setSchema

How could I write this loop?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, let me explain this...

The main point in my solution is to create some thing like `headtag` and `fieldname{}`to record the stream from `fs` which read csv row by row. I use the headtag to validate the round of the streaming rows. For example for the first round, I need the row's value to be the key of every object in my final json file. If I set a `header` in `fromStream()` method, each round's result will conatin the header, I dont know how to 'merge' them, so I chose this 'tricky' way.

Then, as in my final json file, some of(not all of) field will be array. So when I read a second value which is not an empty string "", I should convert the field into an array.using`readResult[fieldnames[i]]=new Array( readResult[fieldnames[i]]);`.

here is the code:

```
//create a fime stream
var stream = fs.createReadStream(csvfilepath);

//as the file will be read row by row, headtag is pointer to row.
//e.g: headtag = 5, means the stream is reading the 5th row of the csv file
var headtag=0;

//the final stream read result, will be the same format in schema.
var readResult={};

//fieldname records the headers key name.
var fieldnames={};
csv.fromStream(stream,{ignoreEmpty:true})
    .on("data", function(data){
    if(headtag === 0){
        //I assume the first row is the headers,so should make sure the headers' names are the same in your schema
        fieldnames = data;
        for(var i=+0; i<data.length; i++){
        readResult["data[i]"] = {};
        }
    }
    if(headtag === 1){
        //some of fields may only conatins one value, so save them as a String
        for(var i=+0; i<data.length; i++){
        readResult[fieldnames[i]] = data[i];
        }
    }
    if(headtag === 2){
        for(var i=+0 ; i<data.length; i++){
        //for those field that may contains multiple values, convert them as an array, then push all values in it.
        if(data[i]!==""){
            readResult[fieldnames[i]]=new Array( readResult[fieldnames[i]]);
             readResult[fieldnames[i]].push(data[i]);
        }
        }
    }
    if(headtag > 2){
        for(var i=+0 ; i<data.length; i++){
                if(data[i]!==""){
                readResult[fieldnames[i]].push(data[i]);
                }
            }
    }
    headtag=headtag+1;
    })
    .on("end",function(){
    readResult.images = images;
    //create a time tag
    var startdate = moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    var starttime = moment().format('H:mm:ss');
    readResult.save_date=startdate;
    readResult.save_time=starttime;
    //save the data in mongodb
    NewHouse.create(readResult, function(error, house){
        if(error){
        console.log(error);
        }
        else{
        console.log("successfully create a document in your mongodb collection!");
        }
    });
    });
```

On the basis of this question, I updated my code. Now you can read both `csv file` and `images` together and save them to mongodb.

for more information check here:
https://github.com/LarryZhao0616/csv_to_json_converter